# Sailsjs - Custom method to find specific attributes

Tags: controller, sails.js

I'm trying create a custom method for select in Controller. I need to get 2 attributes from model, but always get error with select method. How to properly create this function?

My model:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    name: 'string',
    city: 'string',
    zipcode: 'string'
}};
```

My select function in Controller:

```
module.exports = {
  findNew({ select: ['name', 'city']});
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a controller method, it needs a lot more code than that. If you know how to code in express, this is basically the same.

If your model was called `Person`, then to do what you want in `PersonController.js` would look like this:

```
module.exports = {
    findNew: function(req, res) {
        Person.find({where: {}, select: ['name', 'city']}).exec(function(err, persons) {
            if (err) {
                // handle the error
            } else {
                return res.send(persons);
            }
        });
    },
};
```

Comment: and when I want to see only one Person name with id: 2 url be like person/2, what should be in where?
`findNew: function(req, res) {
   Person.findOne({where: {???}, select: ['name']}).exec(function(err, persons) {
            if (err) {
                // handle the error
            } else {
                return res.send(persons);
            }
        });`

Comment: It requires some setup in your routes.js file... an important question is, you are trying to write your own custom method, and not use the default blueprint api correct?

Comment: I added my routes and Controller to new answer for better view.

Comment: @Torrado36 You should add the new info to the original question instead. The routes and controller you posted look good. If they aren't doing what you expect, start console.log'ing the `err` or `items` objects to see what's up.

Answer (score 0):

in sails 1.0v

```
findNew: async (req, res) => {
        const result = await Person.find({where: {}, select: ['name', 'city']});
        res.json(result);
    }
```